# Python - Why is my Tkinter window not closing on self.destroy?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am currently creating a little program which inserts Tkinter Entry boxes into Google Calendar (after all different kind of checks ofcourse). That part is not the problem.
Since I am running a terminal at the same time that I don't want to 'hold' during the Tkinter window is open.

When I close the window using

```
def quit(self):
    self.thread.stop()
    self.destroy()
```

All the parts of the window disappear, but the window stays on screen.

```
class window(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, thread):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

    self.parent = parent
    self.w = 600
    self.h = 400

    self.initUI()
    self.center()
    self.thread = thread
```

I use this funciton to create the class:

```
def main(thread):

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
app = window(root, thread)
root.mainloop()
```

The myThread class.

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self,threadType):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadType = threadType
    self.event = threading.Event()
def stop(self):
    self.event.set()
def run(self):
    if self.threadType == "new_app":
        newappoint.main(self)
    elif self.threadType == "main":
        main()
```

Can anybody tell me if I missed something that would make the window close properly.
The thread is closed after calling the `self.quit()`

Comment: tkinter and threads do not mix well, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556479/running-a-tkinter-form-in-a-separate-thread

Comment: @shivsn That worked, thank you :)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala So basically it would be better to only thread my original main function and then keep the `if __name__ == __main__:` looping looking for a variable to change and launch Tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `self.destroy()` do this `self.parent.destroy()`.

As far as my understanding we are passing `tk` object to the class `window` and it used as `parent` in the class.So instead of using `root` to create widgets we are using `parent`.

Comment: Can you explain why it helps?

Comment: Thanks. You should add this explanation to the answer.