# Program keeps running if TK window closed too fast

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, queue

Python GUI with Tk that a user adds servers to and it displays port and resource information about the server. Each server line is running in its own thread and loops with a `myQueue.put(executor.submit(lambda: <function here>))`. I can load up 15 servers and then close the window. Sometimes the python.exe closes and the IDE shows the application end with exit code 0. Sometimes I close the window and the IDE and task manager show that the program is still running. After a while the pycharm console prints "main thread is not in main loop" and nothing else happens after that. I thought using a queue with the threads would keep this from happening but something is going wrong.

Workflow for the below code: user adds server info in a popup window> that is run through creation function> information is passed off to threadmaker function that watches an indicator and reruns the SSH session to query info when the previous query finishes.

```
main = Tk()
myQueue = queue.Queue()
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16)

def creation(server, nickname, user, passw):

    #Create label for server, nickname, user, password here and place them on the main window

    myQueue.put(executor.submit(lambda: threadmaker(server, nickname, user, passw)))

def threadmaker(server, nickname,  user, passw):
    # this function loops until indicator is 0 and then runs refresh function
    global workinglist
    if 'normal' == main.state():
        if workinglist[server + "counter"] == "1":
            time.sleep(3)
            myQueue.put(executor.submit(threadmaker(server, nickname, user, passw)))
        if workinglist[server + "counter"] == "0":
            myQueue.put(executor.submit(refresh(server, nickname, user, passw)))
            time.sleep(3)
            myQueue.put(executor.submit(threadmaker(server, nickname, user, passw)))

    if 'normal' != main.state():
        print(main.state())
        pass

def refresh(server, nickname, user, passw):
    global workinglist
    workinglist[server + "counter"] = "1"
    if 'normal' == main.state():
                if 'normal' == main.state():
                    try:
                        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
                        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
                        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                        ssh.connect(str(server), username=str(user), password=str(passw), timeout=10, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
                        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("DF -H")
                        type(stdin)
                        test2 = stdout.readlines()
                        stdin.flush()
                        stdin.close()
                        ssh.close()
                         #<< do soething with the test2 value>>

                    except Exception as E:
                        print(E)

                if 'normal' == main.state():
                    try:
                        #<< another ssh query >>
                    except Exception as E:
                        pass
    workinglist[server + "counter"] = "0"

main.mainloop()
```

Am I handling the threads or the queue incorrectly?

I've added `print(threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Starting')` to the beginning of the refresh function and the running thread number never gets over the number of servers added + 1 for the main thread. So if Im handling all the threads with my threadpool what is hanging up? I assume something with the ssh attempt.

Comment: Add exit() at the end of thread_loop and run, to check if python.exe is the threads or the main program

Comment: @Radagast I added exit() at the end of the refresh function ( I assume this is where you meant to put it ) and im still able to cause the hangup. Something else I noticed- after posting to SO I left the machine for ~1 hour and when I came back the program seemed to exit every time without an issue. Relaunching 4 or 5 times finally replicated the issue but I thought it was odd.  I only see the "main thread is not in main loop" message when the hangup happens.

Comment: Now the hangup seems to happen every time I run from the IDE. This makes the issue seem more random or like it only happens if its closed during a specific process thats running. I'll update the question with this.

Comment: I figured out what is happen, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556479/running-a-tkinter-form-in-a-separate-thread/10556698#10556698

Comment: @Radagast They mention the program gui freezing in that thread. Just to clarify, my gui does not freeze when im doing anything. Its just on the close. That being said I see what they are saying about putting the results in a queue and letting the main thread watch that queue for updates. How would I put changes to a Label into the queue and let the main thread apply that change? if I run a loop in the main thread that watches a queue it will cause the gui to freeze. To avoid that I have to run the loop in a new thread which leads back to the same problem.