# Tkinter object has no attribute

Tags: python, tkinter

I get the following error in python 2.7, under the method `updateText` when I try to call `self.editArea.insert()`.

```
AttributeError: 'App2' object has no attribute 'editArea'
```

My code is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import threading

class App2(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
        self.root.geometry("200x100")
        self.COMframe = tk.Frame(self.root, width=200, height=100, bg = '#ffffff', borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.COMframe)
        self.editArea = tk.Text(self.COMframe, width=200, height=100, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.editArea.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.editArea.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.COMframe.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #self.editArea.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        #self.editArea.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.editArea.insert(tk.END, "hello world\n this is my text")
        #self.editArea.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def updateText(self, string):
        #self.editArea.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        #self.editArea.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.editArea.insert(tk.END, string)
        #self.editArea.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

app2 = App2()

r = 0
while True:
    s = "r={}".format(r)
    app2.updateText(s)

    r = r+1
    print s
```

I don't understand why python won't see `editArea`. Does it have to do with the fact that it is declared in `run(self)`?

Comment: The assignment to `self.editArea` is like any other assignment; it will happen when `run` is *called*, not defined. If it needs to be used in other methods, you need to either move it to `__init__` or guaranteed that `run` will be called before `updateText`.

Comment: i assume that the 'run' method was called because the tkinter GUI pops up when I take out the 'updateText' method.

Comment: You have a race condition in your code. The `run` method may not have reached the line creating `self.editArea` by the time you call `updateText` in the main thread. I'd suggest moving the creation of the TK components into the `__init__` function.

Comment: Also be aware you should not run the mainloop anywhere except the main thread see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You define `self.editText` in the `run` method, but you never call the `run` method (or you call it by some code you didn't show us).

Bottom line: you must define an instance variable before you try to use it, but your code is running in an order where `updateText` is being called before `run`, which can be proven with a couple of print statements.