# Python real time plotting ROS data

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, python-multithreading, rospy

I am trying to plot real time data coming to the computer using python. Data comes in a ROS topic and I use 'rospy' to subscribe to the topic in order to get data.
This is the code I wrote

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import ChannelFloat32
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 200
i = 0

topic = "chatter"

x = range(N)
lmotor = [0]*N
rmotor = [0]*N

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0,N])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])

line1, = ax.plot(lmotor, 'r-')
line2, = ax.plot(rmotor, 'g')

def plotThrottle(data):
    global x, lmotor, rmotor, i

    [x[i],lmotor[i],rmotor[i], tmp] = data

    line1.set_ydata(lmotor)
    line1.set_xdata(x)
    line2.set_ydata(rmotor)
    line2.set_xdata(x)

    fig.canvas.draw()

def callBack(packet):
    data = list(packet.values)
    plotThrottle(data)


def listner():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber(topic, ChannelFloat32, callBack)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listner()
```

My problem is when I call `plotThrottle()` with the data I got from rostopic, I get following error.

```
[ERROR]
[WallTime: 1454388985.317080] bad callback: <function callBack at 0x7f13d98ba6e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "dummy2.py", line 41, in callBack
    plotThrottle(data)
  File "dummy2.py", line 37, in plotThrottle
    fig.canvas.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 349, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 13, in blit
    tk.call("PyAggImagePhoto", photoimage, id(aggimage), colormode, id(bbox_array))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

But if I use the same function and pass some data generated within the code (some random data) plot works fine.
I am an absolute beginner to python. I searched about this error and it says that this is because of some threading problem. But I don't understand how to fix this code. I am really grateful if someone can explain the problem and help fix this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have two threads running, rospy.spin() and top.mainloop() (from Tkinter, backend of matplotlib in your case).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop):

> The problems stem from the fact that the _tkinter module attempts to
> gain control of the main thread via a polling technique when
> processing calls from other threads.
>
> Your Tkinter code in Thread-1 is trying to peek into the main thread
> to find the main loop, and it's not there.

From [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/106781/rospy-and-tkinter-spin-and-mainloop/):

> If there is another blocking call that keeps your program running,
> there is no need to call rospy.spin(). Unlike in C++ where spin() is
> needed to process all the threads, in python all it does is block.

So you can use `plt.show(block=True)` to keep your program from closing, in that case you will use Tkinter mainloop, redrawing your canvas without problems.

The listener fuction should look like this:

```
    def listener():
        rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber(topic, ChannelFloat32, callBack)
        # rospy.spin()
        plt.show(block=True)
```

Anyway this seems a bit a workaround for other alternatives see again [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop) or simply use separate node for plotting i.e. ros suggested tools like [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Using_rqt_plot).

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an old post and still seems to be active in the community, I am going to provide an example, in general, how can we do real-time plotting. Here I used matplotlib [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rospy
import tf
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf.transformations import quaternion_matrix
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


class Visualiser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')
        self.x_data, self.y_data = [] , []

    def plot_init(self):
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 10000)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)
        return self.ln
    
    def getYaw(self, pose):
        quaternion = (pose.orientation.x, pose.orientation.y, pose.orientation.z,
                pose.orientation.w)
        euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
        yaw = euler[2] 
        return yaw   

    def odom_callback(self, msg):
        yaw_angle = self.getYaw(msg.pose.pose)
        self.y_data.append(yaw_angle)
        x_index = len(self.x_data)
        self.x_data.append(x_index+1)
    
    def update_plot(self, frame):
        self.ln.set_data(self.x_data, self.y_data)
        return self.ln


rospy.init_node('lidar_visual_node')
vis = Visualiser()
sub = rospy.Subscriber('/dji_sdk/odometry', Odometry, vis.odom_callback)

ani = FuncAnimation(vis.fig, vis.update_plot, init_func=vis.plot_init)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Note: change the `rospy.Subscriber('/dji_sdk/odometry', Odometry, vis.odom_callback)` as you need and do necessary changes accordingly.