# How can I print the time (in seconds) in Zelle's Graphic Window?

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

I was wondering how you can print the time (in seconds) in a graphics window. I am trying to make a stop watch, and I have the stop watch png displayed in a window, but how can I show the time in the window in a specific area?
Also, is there a way to format the time like a real stop watch (hh:mm:ss) where after 60 seconds it adds 1 minute?

```
from graphics import *
import time

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Stopwatch', 600, 600)
    win.yUp()

    #Assigning images
    stopWatchImage = Image(Point (300, 300), "stopwatch.png")
    startImage = Image(Point (210, 170), "startbutton.png")
    stopImage = Image(Point (390, 170), "stopbutton.png")
    lapImage = Image(Point (300, 110), "lapbutton.png")

    #Drawing images
    stopWatchImage.draw(win)
    startImage.draw(win)
    stopImage.draw(win)
    lapImage.draw(win)

main()
```

Comment: You will need some window-related library, e. g. pygtk ;-)

Comment: Sorry I'm new, I don't quite understand.

Comment: If you are new, I wouldn't recommend a stopwatch that increments time "in real time"... That would require you to know threads and how to redraw on the window on intervals of seconds

Comment: I have added the code, @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 would I be able to make a "fake" time and just have it go up by 1 second up to 100000 seconds or something?

Comment: For starters, you want to create a `Text` object, don't you?

Comment: Yes that would be placed where the time would go.

Comment: And so, that should answer two of your questions: how to place and format it...

Comment: So then how can I increment it by 1 second..?

Comment: Like I said, threads. Maybe a `Timer` object. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: Actually, just tried to implement this myself, and Zelle Graphics is not thread safe, so I don't think you can just re-draw components like this.

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible, you could try the following but you'll notice this error upon running...

[RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop#14695007)

(Zelle Graphics is just a wrapper around Tkinter)

Comment out all the graphics stuff, and you'll see the print statements increment every second.

```
from graphics import *
import datetime
from threading import Thread
import time

class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timestamp = datetime.time(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return datetime.time.strftime(self.timestamp, '%H:%M:%S')

    def increment(self, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=1):
        dummy_date = datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
        full_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(dummy_date, self.timestamp)
        full_datetime += datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds, hours=hours, minutes=minutes)
        self.timestamp = full_datetime.time()


def main():
    win = GraphWin('Stopwatch', 600, 600)
    watch = StopWatch()

    timer_text = Text(Point(200, 200), str(watch))
    timer_text.draw(win)

    def updateWatch():
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            watch.increment()
            print(str(watch))
            timer_text.setText(str(watch))

    t1 = Thread(target=updateWatch)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

    win.getMouse()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, so what you're saying is, it's not possible. @cricket_007

Comment: As far as I can tell, not with Zelle Graphics, but maybe another Python Graphics library.

Comment: Hello @cricket_007, i was able to get it to work with time.sleep(1) and text in Zelles graphics. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to either accept my answer, or answer the post with your own solution