# Error when trying to run two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, turtle-graphics

I have two different methods, one controls a turtle with the arrow keys, and the other controls an array of automated turtles. When I run the program I get this error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function falconMove at 0x7f6c9af61aa0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/FinalProject.py", line 198, in falconMove
    wn.onkey(up, "Up")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 1343, in onkey
    self._onkey(fun, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 711, in _onkey
    self.cv.bind("<KeyRelease-%s>" % key, eventfun)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 440, in bind
    self._canvas.bind(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1098, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1048, in _bind
    needcleanup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1220, in _register
    self.tk.createcommand(name, f)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function evilMove at 0x7f6c9af61b18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/FinalProject.py", line 211, in evilMove
    traveler.forward(travelerSpeed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 1553, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 1521, in _go
    self._goto(ende)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 2991, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 761, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2300, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args)))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

This is the code used by the threads.

```
def falconMove(a):
    time.sleep(.1)
    global wn
    wn.onkey(up, "Up")
    wn.onkey(left, "Left")
    wn.onkey(right, "Right")
    wn.onkey(down, "Down")
    wn.listen()

def evilMove(a):
    time.sleep(.1)
    global alive
    global success
    global blockNum
    global traveler
    global travelerSpeed
    traveler.forward(travelerSpeed)

    for i in range(0, len(evil), 1):
        evil[i].forward(speed[i] + (travelerSpeed * 2))
        for j in range(0, len(evil), 1):
            if collide(turt, evil[j]):
                alive = False
                success = False
            if collide(traveler, evil[j]):
                alive = False
                success = False
        if evil[i].ycor() < -(height / 2):
            evilReset(i, False)
        if collide(turt, nice):
            blockNum += 1
            nice.goto(random.randint(-(width / 2) + 20, (width / 2) - 20),
                      random.randint(-(height / 2) + 120, (height / 2) - 20))
            buildBlock(blockNum, True)
        if blockNum == 9 or traveler.xcor() > width / 2:
            success = True
            alive = False


thread.start_new_thread(falconMove, (1,))
thread.start_new_thread(evilMove, (1,))
```

If needed this is the whole program

```
import turtle
import random
import gtk
import threading
import thread
import time

travelerSpeed = 0
while travelerSpeed > 10 or travelerSpeed < 1:
    travelerSpeed = input("Enter the difficulty(1-10): ")

#Turtle Settings
wn = turtle.Screen()
falcon = "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/ship.gif"
falconR = "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/shipR.gif"
falconL = "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/shipL.gif"
falconD = "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/shipD.gif"
wn.addshape(falcon)
turt = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turt.pu()
turt.shape(falcon)
turt.fillcolor("snow")
turt.goto(0, 0)

#Screen Setup
window = gtk.Window()
screen = window.get_screen()
width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()
wn.screensize()
wn.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)

#Key Action Handelers
def up():
    global falcon
    turt.setheading(90)
    #turt.shape(falcon)
    turt.forward(2)

def left():
    global falconL
    turt.setheading(180)
    #turt.shape(falconL)
    turt.forward(2)

def right():
    global falconR
    turt.setheading(0)
    #turt.shape(falconR)
    turt.forward(2)

def down():
    global falconD
    turt.setheading(270)
    #turt.shape(falconD)
    turt.forward(2)

#Supports on the Bottom
builder = turtle.Turtle()
builder.tracer(0)
builder.pencolor("snow")
builder.fillcolor("snow")
builder.ht()
startx = -width/2
starty = (-height/2) + 100
blockWidth = width/10
blockHeight = 50

def buildBlock(num, fill):
    builder.pu()
    builder.goto(startx + (blockWidth*num), starty)
    builder.pd()
    if fill:
        builder.begin_fill()
    builder.setheading(0)
    for i in range(2):
        builder.forward(blockWidth)
        builder.right(90)
        builder.forward(blockHeight)
        builder.right(90)

    if fill:
        builder.end_fill()

for i in range(10):
    buildBlock(i, False)

#Make the helpless traveler
traveler = turtle.Turtle()
traveler.pu()
traveler.pensize(2)
traveler.goto(-width/2, (-height/2) + 25)
traveler.setheading(0)
traveler.pencolor("navy")
traveler.pd()
traveler.pensize(3)

#Laser Colors
colors = ["blue2", "green2", "red", "purple3", "snow", "yellow2"]

#Declare Nice Guy
nice = turtle.Turtle()
nice.shape("circle")
nice.fillcolor("cyan")
nice.pencolor("cyan")
nice.pu()
nice.goto(random.randint((-width / 2) + 20, (width / 2) - 20), random.randint((-height/2) + 120, (height / 2) - 20))

#Declare Evil Entities
e0 = turtle.Turtle()
e1 = turtle.Turtle()
e2 = turtle.Turtle()
e3 = turtle.Turtle()
e4 = turtle.Turtle()
e5 = turtle.Turtle()
e6 = turtle.Turtle()
e7 = turtle.Turtle()
e8 = turtle.Turtle()
e9 = turtle.Turtle()
e10 = turtle.Turtle()
e12 = turtle.Turtle()
e13 = turtle.Turtle()
e14 = turtle.Turtle()
e15 = turtle.Turtle()
e16 = turtle.Turtle()
e17 = turtle.Turtle()
e18 = turtle.Turtle()
e19 = turtle.Turtle()
e20 = turtle.Turtle()
e21 = turtle.Turtle()
e22 = turtle.Turtle()
e23 = turtle.Turtle()
e24 = turtle.Turtle()
e25 = turtle.Turtle()
e26 = turtle.Turtle()
e27 = turtle.Turtle()
e28 = turtle.Turtle()
e29 = turtle.Turtle()
e30 = turtle.Turtle()
e31 = turtle.Turtle()
e32 = turtle.Turtle()
e33 = turtle.Turtle()
e34 = turtle.Turtle()
e35 = turtle.Turtle()
e36 = turtle.Turtle()
e37 = turtle.Turtle()
e38 = turtle.Turtle()
e39 = turtle.Turtle()
e40 = turtle.Turtle()
e41 = turtle.Turtle()
e42 = turtle.Turtle()
e43 = turtle.Turtle()
e44 = turtle.Turtle()
e45 = turtle.Turtle()
e46 = turtle.Turtle()
e47 = turtle.Turtle()
e48 = turtle.Turtle()
e49 = turtle.Turtle()

evil = [e0, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, e12, e13, e14, e15, e16, e17, e18, e19, e20, e21, e22, e23, e24, e25, e26, e27, e28, e29, e30, e31, e32, e33, e34, e35, e36, e37, e38, e39, e40, e41, e42, e43, e44, e45, e46, e47, e48, e49,]
speed = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
difficulty = [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]

def evilReset(i, first):
    if difficulty[i] < 10:
        difficulty[i] += 1
    evil[i].tracer(0)
    if first:
        evil[i].goto(random.randint(-(width / 2), (width / 2)), random.randint((height / 2), (height * 1.5)))
    else:
        evil[i].goto(random.randint(-(width / 2), (width / 2)), random.randint((height / 2), (height/2 + 30)))
    evil[i].tracer(1)
    speed[i] = random.randint(5, difficulty[i])
    evil[i].fillcolor(colors[random.randint(0, 5)])
    evil[i].setheading(270)

for i in range(0, len(evil), 1):
    evil[i].pu()
    evilReset(i, True)

def collide(turt1, turt2):
    if turt1.xcor() - turt2.xcor() < 10:
        if turt.ycor() - nice.ycor() < 10:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

alive = True
success = False
blockNum = -1

def falconMove(a):
    time.sleep(.1)
    global wn
    wn.onkey(up, "Up")
    wn.onkey(left, "Left")
    wn.onkey(right, "Right")
    wn.onkey(down, "Down")
    wn.listen()

def evilMove(a):
    time.sleep(.1)
    global alive
    global success
    global blockNum
    global traveler
    global travelerSpeed
    traveler.forward(travelerSpeed)

    for i in range(0, len(evil), 1):
        evil[i].forward(speed[i] + (travelerSpeed * 2))
        for j in range(0, len(evil), 1):
            if collide(turt, evil[j]):
                alive = False
                success = False
            if collide(traveler, evil[j]):
                alive = False
                success = False
        if evil[i].ycor() < -(height / 2):
            evilReset(i, False)
        if collide(turt, nice):
            blockNum += 1
            nice.goto(random.randint(-(width / 2) + 20, (width / 2) - 20),
                      random.randint(-(height / 2) + 120, (height / 2) - 20))
            buildBlock(blockNum, True)
        if blockNum == 9 or traveler.xcor() > width / 2:
            success = True
            alive = False


thread.start_new_thread(falconMove, (1,))
thread.start_new_thread(evilMove, (1,))


#for thread in thread_list:
#    thread.start()
#    thread.join()

while alive:
    #Turtle Movement
    pass


if success:
    exit()
    print("Congrats you Won")
else:
    exit()
    print("You suck better luck next time")

print("The End")

#turtle.mainloop()
```

I know the code is messy, and it is not a working program, I just want to get the threading to work first. Thanks :)

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop) and linked questions.

Comment: BTW: you could use `for` loop to create "Evil Entities" - code would be shorter without all this `e0`, `e49`

Comment: most GUI has to run in main thread. `turtle` uses `tkinter` which is not `thread-safe` so it should run only in main thread. You can run other elements in other thread (some calculations) but you have to use GUI elements (widgets, events) only in main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you need a thread to do what you want -- you may be able to simply use the turtle `ontimer()` event.  I've reworked your code along these lines to demonstrate such:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

travelerSpeed = 0
while travelerSpeed > 10 or travelerSpeed < 1:
    travelerSpeed = int(input("Enter the difficulty(1-10): "))

# Screen Setup
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
width = screen.window_width()
height = screen.window_height()

# Turtle Settings
# falcon = "/home/bernardk/Code/Python/FinalProject/ship.gif"
# screen.addshape(falcon)

turt = Turtle(shape="turtle")
turt.speed("fastest")
turt.fillcolor("snow")
turt.pu()
turt.goto(0, 0)

# Key Action Handlers
def up():
    turt.setheading(90)
    turt.forward(2)

def left():
    turt.setheading(180)
    turt.forward(2)

def right():
    turt.setheading(0)
    turt.forward(2)

def down():
    turt.setheading(270)
    turt.forward(2)

# Supports on the Bottom
builder = Turtle(visible=False)
builder.color("snow")

startx = -width / 2
starty = (-height / 2) + 100
blockWidth = width / 10
blockHeight = 50

def buildBlock(num, fill):
    builder.pu()
    builder.goto(startx + (blockWidth * num), starty)
    builder.pd()

    if fill:
        builder.begin_fill()

    builder.setheading(0)
    for _ in range(2):
        builder.forward(blockWidth)
        builder.right(90)
        builder.forward(blockHeight)
        builder.right(90)

    if fill:
        builder.end_fill()

screen.tracer(0)
for i in range(10):
    buildBlock(i, False)
screen.tracer(1)

# Make the helpless traveler
traveler = Turtle()
traveler.pensize(3)
traveler.pencolor("navy")
traveler.setheading(0)
traveler.pu()
traveler.goto(-width / 2, -height / 2 + 25)
traveler.pd()

# Laser Colors
colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "purple", "white", "yellow"]

# Declare Nice Guy
nice = Turtle(shape="circle")
nice.pencolor("cyan")
nice.pu()
nice.goto(random.randint((-width / 2) + 20, (width / 2) - 20), random.randint((-height / 2) + 120, (height / 2) - 20))

# Declare Evil Entities
evil = [Turtle() for _ in range(50)]
speed = [0] * len(evil)
difficulty = [6] * len(evil)

def evilReset(i, first):
    if difficulty[i] < 10:
        difficulty[i] += 1
    if first:
        evil[i].goto(random.randint(-width // 2, width // 2), random.randint(-height // 2, height // 2))
    else:
        evil[i].goto(random.randint(-width // 2, width // 2), random.randint(-height // 2 + 30, height // 2))
    speed[i] = random.randint(5, difficulty[i])
    evil[i].fillcolor(random.choice(colors))
    evil[i].setheading(270)

screen.tracer(0)
for i, entity in enumerate(evil):
    entity.pu()
    evilReset(i, True)
screen.tracer(1)

def collide(turt1, turt2):
    if turt1.xcor() - turt2.xcor() < 10:
        return turt1.ycor() - turt2.ycor() < 10

    return False

alive = True
success = False
blockNum = -1

def evilMove():
    global alive
    global success
    global blockNum

    traveler.forward(travelerSpeed)

    for i in range(len(evil)):
        evil[i].forward(speed[i] + (travelerSpeed * 2))
        for j in range(len(evil)):
            if collide(turt, evil[j]):
                alive = False
                success = False
            if collide(traveler, evil[j]):
                alive = False
                success = False
        if evil[i].ycor() < -(height / 2):
            evilReset(i, False)
        if collide(turt, nice):
            blockNum += 1
            nice.goto(random.randint(-(width / 2) + 20, (width / 2) - 20), random.randint(-(height / 2) + 120, (height / 2) - 20))
            buildBlock(blockNum, True)
        if blockNum == 9 or traveler.xcor() > width / 2:
            success = True
            alive = False

    if not alive:
        if success:
            print("Congrats you Won")
        else:
            print("You suck, better luck next time")

        print("The End")
        exit()

    screen.ontimer(evilMove, 100)

screen.onkey(up, "Up")
screen.onkey(left, "Left")
screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.onkey(down, "Down")
screen.listen()

screen.ontimer(evilMove, 100)

screen.mainloop()
```

It's not perfect but should give you a sense of what's possible.