# Tkinter labels unwantedly randomly disappears

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have created a code that takes random "cocktail of the day" from JSON. Everything works great:

- click on image refreshes data,
- click on Fav icon stores current data in sql (like an local archive),
- click on the header changes from online/local version and vice versa.

Now, data manipulation works great, but on the header I have two labels: "label_online" whick text changes from online to archive depending on source, and "Category" which shows cocktail category. They both work as they should, but the problem is they randomly disappear when I click on header. On every click they act randomly, sometimes they disappear, sometimes they don't.

```
import io
import json
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import sqlite3
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime_str = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
id = "4d4-" + datetime_str
date_str = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y.")

conn = sqlite3.connect('cocktails.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cocktails_4d4 (
              id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
              name_4d4 TEXT,
              instructions_4d4 TEXT,
              photo_path_4d4 TEXT,
              ingredients_4d4 TEXT,
              category_4d4 TEXT,
              date_4d4 TEXT
          )
          ''')

def do_resize():  # <-- return to original size
    root.geometry('520x280')

def do_refresh():
    root.geometry('520x281')   # <-- temporary change window size by 1 px to avoid label disappear
    root.after(5, do_resize)  # <-- return it to original size

def change_title(new_title):
    root.title(new_title)

def update_cocktail_image(event=None):
    global id, cocktail, instructions, ingredients, category, cocktail_photo_path, date_str, datetime_str, image2

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    datetime_str = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    id = "4d4-" + datetime_str
    date_str = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y.")

    url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php'
    response = urlopen(url)
    data_json = json.loads(response.read())

    cocktail_photo_fav1.configure(image=image_fav1)

    cocktail = data_json['drinks'][0]['strDrink']
    instructions = data_json['drinks'][0]['strInstructions']
    cocktail_name.config(text=cocktail)
    cocktail_inst.config(text=instructions)

    change_title(f'Cocktail of the day - {cocktail}')
    
    cocktail_photo_path = data_json['drinks'][0]['strDrinkThumb']
    response = requests.get(cocktail_photo_path)
    image_data = response.content
    image2 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data)).resize((120, 120))
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
    cocktail_photo.configure(image=image2)
    cocktail_photo.image = image2

    ingredients = ""
    for i in range(1, 16):
        ingredient = data_json['drinks'][0].get(f'strIngredient{i}')
        measure = data_json['drinks'][0].get(f'strMeasure{i}')
        if ingredient and measure:
            ingredients += f"{measure} {ingredient}\n"
    cocktail_ingredients.configure(text=ingredients)
    #print(ingredients)
    category=data_json['drinks'][0]['strCategory']  
    category_lbl.configure(text=f'Category: {category}')   
    #print(datetime_str)
    do_refresh()

cocktail_displayed = False


def save_or_delete_cocktail(event):
    if header.cget('bg') == 'darkred':
        confirm_delete()
    else:
        save_cocktail()


def confirm_delete():
    global confirm_label, confirm_button, cancel_button
    confirm_label = tk.Label(footer, text="Delete?", font=('Segoe UI', 10), bg='darkgoldenrod', fg='white')
    confirm_label.pack(padx=20, pady=10, side='left')
    confirm_button = tk.Button(footer, text="Yes, delete it", font=('Segoe UI', 10), bg='darkgoldenrod', fg='white', command=cocktail_delete)
    confirm_button.pack(padx=10,pady=10,side='left')

    def cancel_deletion():
        #confirm_window.destroy()
        confirm_label.pack_forget()
        confirm_button.pack_forget()
        cancel_button.pack_forget()
        confirm_button.pack_forget() 
        cocktail_photo_fav1.configure(image=image_fav2)
        
    cancel_button = tk.Button(footer, text="No, cancel", font=('Segoe UI', 10), bg='darkgoldenrod', fg='white', command=cancel_deletion)
    cancel_button.pack(padx=20, pady=10, side='left')

def cocktail_delete():
    global id
    conn = sqlite3.connect('cocktails.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    curr_id=cocktail_id.cget('text')
    #print(curr_id)
    
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM cocktails_4d4 WHERE id=?", (curr_id,))
    conn.commit()

    #print(f"Cocktail {curr_id} deleted")
    previous_cocktail()
    confirm_label.pack_forget()
    confirm_button.pack_forget()
    cancel_button.pack_forget()
    confirm_button.pack_forget() 
    cocktail_photo_fav1.configure(image=image_fav2)

def save_cocktail():
    #cocktail_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO cocktails_4d4 (id, name_4d4, instructions_4d4, photo_path_4d4, ingredients_4d4, category_4d4, date_4d4)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            ''', (id, cocktail, instructions, cocktail_photo_path, ingredients, category, date_str))

    conn.commit()
    #conn.close()
    cocktail_photo_fav1.configure(image=image_fav2)
    global cocktail_displayed
    cocktail_displayed = True
    print(f'cocktail {cocktail} saved')

def update_cocktail_labels(row):
    global cocktail_id
    cocktail_id.configure(text=row[0])
    cocktail_name.configure(text=row[1])
    cocktail_inst.configure(text=row[2])
    #------------------------------------
    cocktail_photo_path = row[3]
    response = requests.get(cocktail_photo_path)
    image_data = response.content
    imagea = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data)).resize((120, 120))
    imagea = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagea)
    cocktail_photo.configure(image=imagea)
    cocktail_photo.image = imagea
    #------------------------------------
    cocktail_ingredients.configure(text=row[4])
    category_lbl.configure(text=row[5])
    #print(row[3])

def previous_cocktail():
    global current_cocktail_index
    current_cocktail_index -= 1
    conn = sqlite3.connect('cocktails.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cocktails_4d4")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if current_cocktail_index < 0:
        current_cocktail_index = len(rows) - 1
    update_cocktail_labels(rows[current_cocktail_index])

def next_cocktail():
    global current_cocktail_index
    current_cocktail_index += 1
    conn = sqlite3.connect('cocktails.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cocktails_4d4")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if current_cocktail_index >= len(rows):
        current_cocktail_index = 0
    update_cocktail_labels(rows[current_cocktail_index])


def change_header():
    if header.cget('bg') == "darkgreen":
        header.config(bg="darkred")
        category_lbl.config(bg="darkred")
        header_online.config(text='Location: | Archive |', bg='darkred')
        do_refresh()

        #print(header.cget('bg'))

        conn = sqlite3.connect('cocktails.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cocktails_4d4")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        
        global current_cocktail_index
        current_cocktail_index = 0
        update_cocktail_labels(rows[current_cocktail_index])
        cocktail_photo_fav1.configure(image=image_fav2)
        # Add the "previous" and "next" buttons
        previous_button.pack(side="left", padx=5)
        next_button.pack(side="right", padx=5)
        footer.configure(text='')
        do_refresh()

    else:
        header.config(bg="darkgreen")
        category_lbl.config(bg="darkgreen")
        header_online.config(text='Location: | Online |', bg='darkgreen')
        do_refresh()
        update_cocktail_image()
        previous_button.pack_forget()
        next_button.pack_forget()
        footer.configure(text="Hit Me    ")
        #print(header.cget('bg'))


#############################################################################################################

url='https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php'

response=urlopen(url)
data_json=json.loads(response.read())

root = tk.Tk()

#json
cocktail=data_json['drinks'][0]['strDrink']# <-- name of the random cocktail
instructions=data_json['drinks'][0]['strInstructions']
ingredients = ""
for i in range(1, 16):
    ingredient = data_json['drinks'][0].get(f'strIngredient{i}')
    measure = data_json['drinks'][0].get(f'strMeasure{i}')
    if ingredient and measure:
        ingredients += f"{measure} {ingredient}\n"
category=data_json['drinks'][0]['strCategory']        


#start
root.title(f'Cocktail of the day - {cocktail}')

root.geometry('520x280')

header = tk.Label(root, text="My Cocktail of the Day  ", font=("Segoe UI", 14, 'bold'), bg="darkgreen", fg="white", height=2, anchor='ne', justify='right')
header.pack(side="top", fill="x")
header.pack_propagate(False)
header.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: change_header())

header_online=tk.Label(header, text='Location: | Online |',font=('Segoe UI', 10), bg='darkgreen', fg='white')
header_online.place(x=15, y=0)

category_lbl=tk.Label(header, text=f'Category: {category}', font=('Segoe UI', 9, "bold"), bg="darkgreen", fg='white')
category_lbl.place(x=302, y=25)

cocktail_photo_path=data_json['drinks'][0]['strDrinkThumb']
response = requests.get(cocktail_photo_path)
image_data = requests.get(cocktail_photo_path).content

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data)).resize((120, 120))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
cocktail_photo = tk.Label(root, image=image, wraplength=100)
cocktail_photo.place(x=20, y=25)
cocktail_photo.bind('<Button-1>', update_cocktail_image)

url_fav1='https://devling.com.hr/webdisk/python/Cocktails/favorite_1.png'
response = requests.get(url_fav1)
image_data_fav1 = requests.get(url_fav1).content
image_fav1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data_fav1)).resize((20, 25))
image_fav1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_fav1)

url_fav2='https://devling.com.hr/webdisk/python/Cocktails/favorite_2.png'
response = requests.get(url_fav2)
image_data_fav2 = requests.get(url_fav2).content
image_fav2 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data_fav2)).resize((20, 25))
image_fav2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_fav2)

cocktail_photo_fav1 = tk.Label(root, image=image_fav1)
cocktail_photo_fav1.place(x=480, y=50)
cocktail_photo_fav1.bind('<Button-1>', save_or_delete_cocktail)

cocktail_ing=tk.Label(root, text='Ingredients: ', font=('Segoe UI', 9, 'bold'), fg='dimgray')
cocktail_ing.place(x=20, y=150)

cocktail_id=tk.Label(root, text='')
cocktail_id.place(x=0, y=0)
cocktail_id.place_forget()

cocktail_ingredients = tk.Label(root, text=ingredients, font=('SegoeUI', 9), anchor='w', justify='left')
cocktail_ingredients.place(x= 20, y=170)

cocktail_name = tk.Label(root, text=cocktail, font=('SegoeUI', 12, 'bold'))
cocktail_name.place(x= 160, y=60)

cocktail_inst = tk.Label(root, text=instructions, font=('SegoeUI', 10), wraplength=350, anchor='w', justify='left')
cocktail_inst.place(x= 160, y=90)

footer = tk.Label(root, text="Hit Me    ", font=("Segoe UI", 13, "bold"), bg="darkgoldenrod", fg="white", height=1, anchor='e', justify='right')
footer.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
footer.bind('<Button-1>', update_cocktail_image)

arrow_char = "\u279c"  
previous_button = tk.Button(footer, text="\u2b98", font=("Wingdings", 9, "bold"), height=1, bg="darkgoldenrod", fg="white", command=previous_cocktail)
previous_button.pack(side="left", padx=5)
previous_button.pack_forget()
next_button = tk.Button(footer, text="\u2b9a", font=("Wingdings", 9, "bold"), bg="darkgoldenrod", fg="white", command=next_cocktail)
next_button.pack(side="right", padx=5)
next_button.pack_forget()

#print(f"Moj odabrani koktel je {cocktail}")
root.mainloop()
```

I've noticed that when they disappear, and I move window border (even for 1px) they appear back, so only solution I could think of was to resize root.geometry by 1px and return it to original size after 5ms.

Here is the code that does that:

```
def do_resize():  # <-- return to original size
    root.geometry('520x280')

def do_refresh():
    root.geometry('520x281')   # <-- temporary change window size by 1 px to avoid label disappear
    root.after(5, do_resize)  # <-- return it to original size
```

and the I call function "do_refresh" on every click on header_online, and it works.
Is there a better solution, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do a network communication in a background thread. Blocking the UI event loop can cause a glitch.

Comment: @Сергей Кох
Sorry, but I've already trim it as much as I could, since this is part of my 4000+ lines of code, and this is the part that bothers me. There are only 10 function and 10 labels (because I need them), without them maybe problem would disappear, but I need them so my program would work as intended.

Comment: @relent95 I've tried it in one of previous versions, but had no luck with it. Do I join it in the end, or leave it ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74989468/1186624).

Comment: @relent95, tnx, it helped (with my other problems), but didn't solve this one.

Comment: Then update the question for your current version which does network communications in a background thread.