# Tkinter window says not responding but code is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, respond-to, mainloop

I am trying to make an antivirus application but I met some issue. And Tkinter window says (not responding) but code is running. I wanted to use threading, but firstly it's not convenient, secondly it doesn't work.I don’t know how to make it so that I can see the window and at the same time the code works. the window stops working after Get Colors In Image is run.

My code:

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry(‘100x100’)

for i in range(100):
    print('hello '+str(i))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mainloop` multiple times?

Comment: Because there is more code

Comment: I want make this code after he choice

Comment: It's unspecific. Research more, implement a prototype(possibly not working code) using a worker thread, and ask a specific question with a [mre]. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74989468/1186624).

Comment: Okay I am edit watch this

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to one of these reasons:

- overload due to other apps using a large amount of your resources
- if this is just the setup, and the antivirus is also in the code, the code may be to large for your OS to handle.